# How to update database without taking down your serivce?

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I'm using ansible to set up my docker-swarm.

In my docker swarm I run: Web server, database, and a cache.
**My question is:** how can I update my database (e.g docker image, etc.) without making the service unavailable?

Should I mirror the existing swarm, and run two identical swarms?
How should I then make sure the update of these is automatic and flawless?

Comment: The scenario you're looking for is [Continuous Delivery and Rolling Upgrades](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_rolling_upgrade.html#continuous-delivery-and-rolling-upgrades).

Comment: I will still have the same problem?..  
Let's forget that I'm using Ansible. The main issue is: **How can I update a database container(s) and it's image in docker swarm without making the service unavailable?**

Comment: @Heihade1 You can use docker-swarm rolling update process wherein you don't need to stop the db services for all the containers but for few initially

Comment: The way I explained it was pretty bad...
I'm running only one service, let's call it test. Which contains the components described.

Comment: And integrating this is CI/CD pipeline won't be that different I guess? 
Push to DockerHub which sends webhook to ansible which updates the swarm?

Answer (score 1):

Docker swarm only permits update services with zero-downtime using parallelism when scale > 1.

You can use parallelism with database, and downtime should me minimum possible, but some seconds are expected.

Check [docker swarm rolling update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/) and [ansible docker swarm service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_swarm_service_module.html) documentation

Definitely, Blue-Green deployment is not an option for database